# Kotlin: eliminate nulls from a List (or other functional transformation)

Tags: types, filter, nullable, kotlin

## Problem

What is the idiomatic way of working around this limitation of the null-safety in the Kotlin type system?

```
val strs1:List<String?> = listOf("hello", null, "world")

// ERROR: Type Inference Failed: Expected Type Mismatch:
// required: List<String>
// round:    List<String?>
val strs2:List<String> = strs1.filter { it != null }
```

This question is not *just* about eliminating nulls, but also to make the type system recognize that the nulls are removed from the collection by the transformation.

I'd prefer not to loop, but I will if that's the best way to do it.

## Work-Around

The following compiles, but I'm not sure it's the best way to do it:

```
fun <T> notNullList(list: List<T?>):List<T> {
    val accumulator:MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
    for (element in list) {
        if (element != null) {
            accumulator.add(element)
        }
    }
    return accumulator
}
val strs2:List<String> = notNullList(strs1)
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use [`filterNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html)

Here is a simple example:

```
val a: List<Int?> = listOf(1, 2, 3, null)
val b: List<Int> = a.filterNotNull()
```

But under the hood, stdlib does the same as you wrote

```
/**
 * Appends all elements that are not `null` to the given [destination].
 */
public fun <C : MutableCollection<in T>, T : Any> Iterable<T?>.filterNotNullTo(destination: C): C {
    for (element in this) if (element != null) destination.add(element)
    return destination
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  Doh!  Why didn't I see that?  :-)

Comment: if you are creating the list you can also use `listOfNotNull`

Comment: I get a Useless call on a collection type warning. Called over a Mutable list<Strings>

Comment: @Xaren It is useless, as your list doesn't contain any nulls. It would be a `List<String?>` otherwise. (Notice the "?")

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
mightContainsNullElementList.removeIf { it == null }
```

Comment: Please explain that further - what does that line do, and why exactly does it solve the given problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase Actually this code speaks for itself. it's quite understandable

Answer (score 0):

```
val strs1 = listOf("hello", null, "world") // [hello, null, world]
val strs2 = strs1.filter { !it.isNullOrBlank() } // [hello, world]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it